# Elements not showing in Brave browser after updating Ubuntu MATE

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate, browser, brave

I recently installed Ubuntu MATE on an old laptop, and installed Brave on it. I used it with no problems for about a week and today I was prompted to perform a system update. After I did, Brave is unusable as most text elements are not showing (see attached screenshots). I have tried restarting the computer multiple times as well as using `sudo apt remove brave-browser` and reinstalling it. The issue persists. Is there any fix for this? Thank you!

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: You've provided no release details; what release of Ubuntu MATE?  The system update detail would be useful if we knew your release, and how often you perform upgrades (*daily? weekly? or something else*), why make us guess, please just tell us.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is worth checking the Brave community forum. I started having trouble with Brave's rendering yesterday, on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. [This thread](https://community.brave.com/t/brave-1-51-118-on-ubuntu-22-04-1/488741) contains several solutions.

The one that worked for me was going to `brave://settings/system` and de-selecting "Use hardware acceleration when available". Now working again.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday my system get the update of "minimal ubuntu" and "standard ubuntu" and since then the icon of Brave Browser on the task bar becomes hidden. Previous times the icon stayed in the start menu of kubuntu but now you can see there a text icon. When you dubble click on the place of the icon on the task bar you can see a text icon and Brave Browser starts. When it started you can see next to the hidden icon the Brave Browser icon on the task bar.